# How to select some fields/tags from an influx DB?

Tags: influxdb

I am able to make a query to an influxdb and select all the fields/tags:

```
select * from http_reqs where time > now() - 4d and "status"  =~ /^4/
```

which returns a list of matching values. The first row looks like this:

```
time error error_code method name proto scenario status tls_version type url value
```

But when I try to select only a subset of these fields/tags (according to the [documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/explore-data/#the-basic-select-statement)), I get no result at all:

```
select "time","name" from http_reqs where time > now() - 4d and "status"  =~ /^4
```

No matter what I try to select. The documentation seems to be wrong or incorrect!

How am I be able to select the fields/tags I want?

Answer (score -1):

It seems you have to first figure out what are "fields" and what are "tags". So you need to do:

```
show field keys from http_reqs;
```

in my case this returns

```
name: http_reqs
fieldKey fieldType
-------- ---------
url      string
value    float
```

As per documentation, you have to use at least one *field key* (for whatever reason).

Then you can query what you need (in addition to the *field key*, if you need that or not):

```
select "url","error" from http_reqs where time > now() - 4d and "status"  =~ /^4/
```